# Configuring .htaccess for PHP-s

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have wordpress on the root of the server. .htaccess is below.
I would like to place a PHP file - say RR.PHP- or even a folder - say RR_FOLDER - holding PHP files at the server's root.
I do not manage to get along with specifying the correct Rewrite rule to achieve that.
Trying the following yields various errors: 404, 501 302

- RewriteRule ^rr.php$
- RewriteRule ^rr.php$ {full_path}/rr.php

I also appended [R] flag which did not help.
What did I miss?

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive Off
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: If you have php files sitting in your root, the `!-f` check will fail and wordpress will ignore them, you don't need any special rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jon Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851273/jon-lin) said, special rules are not needed.
The file permissions and the file owner should be appropriate to the user own the server.

You can copy the permissions from wp-content.php(or other running/working php file) to other file with:
`chmod -R --reference=wp-admin yourFiles`
In addition make sure the right user is own the file.
If not change owner with:
`chown <userName> yourFiles`

Answer (score 1):

You can try these rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(rr\.php)$ full_path/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That is your rewrite rule should come before WP standard rules.

Comment: I found the problem:
its the file permissions and the file owner...
I simply copy the  permissions from wp-content to my own files.
I do it with:
chmod -R --reference=wp-admin myFiles
as the right user – not as the root.